# Excel VBA 1004 Error formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, runtime

I've been working in VBA for about a month now, and I feel like I have a decent command of the language. Unfortunately, that's why this error is so frustrating.

I'm trying to assign a formula to a cell, and I'm not using UK-style separators (so commas, instead of semicolons). I'm still getting the runtime error.

The syntax of the actual formula is fine, as I've tried using it in Excel, and it does what I need it to, so I have to assume the error is in my VBA syntax, below:

```
    With DecileChooser
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.PasteSpecial

    Range("I1").Value = CurrentPD
    Range("I2").Value = CompanyDomain


    DecileChooser.Range("J2").Formula = "=IF($I$1 > D2, G2, "")"

    Range("J2:J11").FillDown

    Range("K1").FormulaLocal = "=max(J1:J11)"

    Range("K1").Value = DecileValue
End With
```

This isn't the entire subroutine, just the operative part.

Comment: `"=IF($I$1 > D2, G2, """")"`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double up on the double quotes:

```
DecileChooser.Range("J2").Formula = "=IF($I$1 > D2, G2, """")"
```

or

```
dq = Chr(34)
DecileChooser.Range("J2").Formula = "=IF($I$1 > D2, G2," & dq & dq & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks! So this is the syntax to be used to referring to empty cells in formulas?

Comment: @Reginald  yes, if VBA is installing the formulas

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the code is reading the double quotation within your formula as the end of the formula, ie what it reads is:

```
DecileChooser.Range("J2").Formula = "=IF($I$1 > D2, G2, "
```

but then has a syntax issue with the remaining ")"

You have to use double quotation marks to indicate that you are not ending the string.

```
With DecileChooser
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.PasteSpecial

Range("I1").Value = CurrentPD
Range("I2").Value = CompanyDomain

DecileChooser.Range("J2").Formula = "=IF($I$1 > D2, G2, """")"

Range("J2:J11").FillDown

Range("K1").FormulaLocal = "=max(J1:J11)"

Range("K1").Value = DecileValue
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Guess it'll take longer than I expected to get used to these quirks in VBA.